# Not able to access the react application which is in the docker images

Tags: reactjs, docker

I've implemented a react application and made into docker. When I run the following command i'm not able to access the react application.
Command :- docker run -p 3000:3000 reactapp

```
> warmup@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

I'm getting the above message but i'm not able to access the react application.

Below is my docker file.

```
FROM node

# A directory within the virtualized Docker environment
# Becomes more relevant when using Docker Compose later
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package*.json ./

# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install

# Copies everything over to Docker environment
COPY . .

# Uses port which is used by the actual application
EXPOSE 3000

# Finally runs the application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: You need to show us your DockerFile

Comment: Hi @kristian I have edited my question to show the docker file

Comment: maybe you need to wait until the bundle is built and served, I think this is the issue since there is no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are hitting https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

You might want to run the docker container with `-it` option.

`docker run -it -p 3000:3000 reactapp`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked with the command that you have provided.

Comment: According to this[1] it seems it is something wrong with the react and docker combination. Is my understanding correct.                                                                                                       [1]  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

Comment: Yes. It's a bug in react-scripts from version 3.4.1. From the issue milestone, looks like the fix will come in version 4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is working perfectly fine.